# Bar under Tab Bar like Flipboard, Swift

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

Does anyone know how to add a bar under the tab bar like Flipboard's iOS app. This question might have an answer somewhere though I cannot seem to find it!

Thanks for the help in advance. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This library could be useful for **tab bar customization & animation**

https://github.com/Ramotion/animated-tab-bar#creating-custom-animations

Comment: @Gugulethu There is an easy way to say thankz ;) click on the upside arrow in front of the answer 

Answer (score -1):

Link below might be very useful. This adds an underline to the uitabbar, this is exactly what you're looking for: 
https://github.com/bfeher/BFPaperTabBarController